# Generating zero-amount transactions in regtest mode?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, transaction-fees, transaction-verification, regtest

I'm setting up a larger test network of regtest nodes in which all of them should be easily capable of creating blocks and sending transactions.
To this end, I'm looking for a simple way for the nodes to be able to submit new transactions into the system, without requiring them to either previously mine blocks, or to introduce a convoluted setup process, e.g, where every node first loads a pre-filled chain state and wallet.

So far I had the hope that it would be possible to create new wallets and addresses and then simply send zero-amount and zero-fee transactions. So far, my efforts are met with a "Transaction amount too small" error.

One 'solution' I found is to write a script that creates new wallets, mines (at least) 101 new blocks to a new address, unloads the wallet and repeats. However, I then would need to distribute the wallets and the blockchain data to all nodes. This seems like a really tedious and error prone setup step to enable a reliable a regtest environment.

Is this possible, can `bitcoind` in regtest mode be reconfigured to accept transactions of value 0? Or is there any other easy way to initiate new addresses or generate new mock transactions, similar to the `generatetoaddress` call for blocks?